# Issues installing Jupyter Notebooks - Python 3.9 - Windows 10

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, git-bash

I am having issues installing Jupyter Notebook. I will preface this by saying I have an elementary understanding of coding and how to properly set up my environment. When using the pip command `pip install jupyter` it begins processing, but I end up with the following error. One issue that I may have is a long file name, but I am unsure how to correct that considering I have never physically used this path. I also have a space between my first and last name in my user folder which may be causing the issue. It is my understanding that changing my username could cause unanticipated downstream issues, so I have not tried to change it.

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\FirstName LastName\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python39\\site-packages\\jedi\\third_party\\typeshed\\third_party\\2and3\\requests\\packages\\urllib3\\packages\\ssl_match_hostname\\_implementation.pyi'
```

I have also tried the following syntax which both end with the above error

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall jupyter
pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall jupyter
```

I tried installing both Anaconda and git bash. When I try to open through Anaconda, it acts like it is processing to open, then just stops and nothing happens.

Using git bash, I have tried the following command. I don't get any errors, but it also does not solve my problem.

```
Anaconda3/Scripts/activate
```

This seems to be a pretty common problem, so I am surprised I haven’t been able to solve it myself. What am I missing?

**Edit:** This is solved, thank you @Dschoni. Using the Anaconda prompt, I typed `jupyter notebook` and it opened.

Comment: Do you know how to open an Anaconda prompt? Inside an Anaconda prompt, you could create a clean conda env, activate it and install jupyter in it.

Comment: Thank you, I had not tried to use the Anaconda prompt, only the GUI. I opened the Anaconda prompt, typed "jupyter notebook" and it opened. Crazy how that works, when nothing else does. Either way, thank you for the help.

Comment: This tells me, there's probably a mess of paths and dependencies. It's very helpfull to have a clean setup before starting. So I would try to thoroughly clean your installation and start with a fresh conda installation and do everything in a conda env (or any other preferred venv).

Comment: @Dschoni It is definitely a mess. I am new to this world and it is easy to see the value of a clean setup. I will take your advice, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when I installed Python on my Windows 10 machine through the Microsoft Store. Once I uninstalled it and installed the version downloaded from the official https://www.python.org/downloads/ this error did not happen anymore.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your comment! I did uninstall/reinstall Python, but it did not fix my problem. My issue was related to a messy path environment mentioned by @Dschoni